# How to exclude a specific MainAccount from an Advanced Rules, in Dynamics AX2012?

Tags: finance, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax

In **Microsoft Dynamics AX2012**, I would like to exclude a specific MainAccount from a Advanced Rules.
I have a General Ledger Rule allowed to all MainAccounts, from this I need to exclude my MainAccount.

For example, the rule JLS_1000 is for all MainAccounts, I need to exclude the MainAccount number 101020 from that rule. (like /IS NOT/ or except).

[image]

I only have the options below.
But I'm not able to get a way to exclude just one MainAccount.

[image]

Thanks and enjoy